# fexpect breaks fabric scripts

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric, fexpect

I hot upon an requirement where I needed to automatically answer the prompt on remote machine and then I found fexpect after reading different stackoverflow questions. But the moment I include fexpect in my script it breaks the whole script!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/main.py", line 743, in main
    *args, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 368, in execute
    multiprocessing
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 264, in _execute
    return task.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 171, in run
    return self.wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/etc/puppet/fabfile.py", line 165, in edit_sudoers
    run('echo "Current Permission of the file /etc/sudoers - "`stat -c "%a %n" /etc/sudoers`')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ilogue/fexpect/api.py", line 15, in run
    wrappedCmd = wrapExpectations(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ilogue/fexpect/internals.py", line 15, in wrapExpectations
    script = createScript(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ilogue/fexpect/internals.py", line 39, in createScript
    for e in fabric.state.env.expectations:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/utils.py", line 184, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: expectations
```

The moment i write 
`from ilogue.fexpect import expect, expecting, run` fabric stops working with the above error message.

I asked in fabric irc as well but I got to know that this might be because of some version related issues. Has anyone else encountered this error before?

fexpect==0.2.post7
Fabric==1.8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just import fexpect's `run` as `erun` and its `sudo` as `esudo`.

When you use the fexpect `run` or `sudo` functions, you *must* wrap those calls in a `with expecting(prompts):` context.  This is a [known issue](https://github.com/ilogue/fexpect/issues/8) in fexpect, although there is a pull request, so it might be fixed by the time posterity reads this.

One solution is to import fexpect's `run` function with a different name, e.g. `erun`, and use it only when you need the automatic prompt handling functionality:

```
from fabric.api import run 
from ilogue.fexpect import expect, expecting, run as erun
run(a_cmd)   # Native Fabric run - should work fine
prompts = [...]
with expecting(prompts):
    erun(a_prompting_cmd)   # fexpect run - should with fine inside expecting context
```

Another thing that isn't explicitly stated in the fexpect documentation is that the `pexpect` package needs to be installed on the target system.

Yet another fexpect gotcha is that the prompt strings are *regular expressions* -- the fexpect sample code is misleading about this.

Comment: Let me try this. Yeah I saw the issue on github and the pull request but let me try your way.